# Find total number of items defined in an enum C#

Tags: c#

Why my code doesn't work?

```
using System;

namespace Enum
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Test.FruitCount);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    enum Fruits { Apple, Orange, Peach }
    public const int FruitCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits)).Length;
}
}
```

I got error

> *Cannot resolve symbol 'GetNames'*

Why? How to fix that?

Comment: Change your namespace from Enum to sth else

Comment: There are a few issues as people have suggested below but the main issue and the reason that you get Cannot resolve sumbol GetNames is your namespace. Check my answer below if you want more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your namespace is **Enum** as well. Its confusing the compiler. Try this:

```
namespace Enum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            Console.WriteLine(test.FruitCount);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        enum Fruits { Apple, Orange, Peach }
        public int FruitCount
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits)).Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I basically fully-qualified **Enum** with `System.Enum.GetNames`

Comment: Because FruitCount was not accessible from the Program class as it is an instance variable (this problem amongst others as well). See my code above for what you need to change and ask me if you have any questions

Answer (score 6):

Because you have made it a constant which can only be a compile time constant.

This works:

```
enum Fruits { Apple, Orange, Peach }
static readonly int FruitCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruits)).Length;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx)

> Constants are immutable values which are known at compile time and do not change for the life of the program.

**Update**: and you also have to change your namespace from `Enum` to something different.

Comment: But if I cant change number of values in enum, why I cant create this constant ?

Comment: @Heidel: The C# compiler won't use reflection to execute `Enum.GetNames` to get the values. So it doesn't know what it is. It must be a compile time constant. The only types that can be `const`  are those that have a literal representation in C#, for example `const string Name = "Tim" + " " + "Schmelter";`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code,

```
public int fruitCount = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruits)).Length;
```

Remember to change the namespace of your file from `Enum` to something elese

Comment: It works fine for me... And +1 because it's more efficient to get the values instead of the names if all you want is the count.

Comment: How can I get my value? I tried this http://pastebin.com/iGtLu5VE , but `Console.WriteLine(GetFruitCount.ToString());` doesnt work?

Comment: `Test t= new Test(); Console.WriteLine(t.GetFruitCount().ToString());` And don't use the same name for class and the namespace